# Wordpress Site Editor - Create taxonomy template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I am currently checking out the new wordpress site editor.
I get how to create templates for different post types, etc, but how do you create a template for a specific taxonomy tpe.

Generaly there is a archive template, but this one template shows for all taxonomy types.
If i want for example a differen sidebar depending on the taxonomy type, can i create seperate templates right now?

Answer (score 0):

you can create file in child theme, name with
like
`archive-your_texonomy_name.php`

`archive-product.php`

Comment: Jea, but this would not integrate into the new site editor.